# TypeScript - Using the <reference path="....."> tag

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

I am trying to add a plugin to the TypeScript compiler and so I added my code and I compiled tsc.ts. It compiles correctly, but when I run, it's missing some variables that are declared in io.ts. I removed my changes, and it still doesn't work. So I tried this:

file: a.ts

```
var a : number = 5;
```

file: b.ts

```
///<reference path='a.ts' />
console.log(a);
```

and then compile: `tsc b.ts` which gives me a.js and b.js.
When I try to run b.js (I do `node b.js`), the variable `a` is undefined.
This is what the content of `b.js`:

```
///<reference path='a.ts' />
console.log(a);
```

and so it makes sense that `a` is undefined, since `a` is nowhere in this file and so is `a.ts`.

Am I compiling it wrong, or executing it wrong.. or what?

Comment: I did a video tutorial on the subject : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1 when you need reference vs. when you use export / import

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running under node, you should use `export` and `import` to manage cross-file dependencies.

**a.ts**

```
export var x = 5;
```

**b.ts**

```
import a = require('./a');
console.log(a.x);
```

Compile with `--module commonjs`

If you were running on the web you could use `--outFile` to concatenate into a single file, but that's usually not a good option under node.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I agree that import/export seems more elegant. But in the typsescript compiler they use <reference>, so I need to do the --out thing... (It works!!) Thank you again!

Comment: What about things like Buffer? I can't seem to find any other way then using reference tags in comments.